# Acttiverecord inverse_of when using single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, single-table-inheritance

I have a system where an account can have many different types of order ( `SalesOrder`, `PurchaseOrder`, `SalesInvoice`, `PurchaseInvoice`, etc)

I'm using single table inheritance and it works really well, even down to the level of controllers and views.

But how do I declare `inverse_of` on the associations.

In my account it's easy on each declaration

```
has_many sales_orders, inverse_of: :account
has_many purchase_orders, inverse_of: account
...
```

But on the base model for all the types of orders I have"

```
belongs_to :account
```

I want to add `inverse_of: xyz` where `xyz` is worked out dynamically according to the model. For example, for a `SaleOrder` in would be `inverse_of: :sales_orders`.

*But* I want to keep the code in the base model. I do not want to go into the SalesOrder and write `belongs_to :account, inverse_of: :sales_orders` there.

How can I do it? Can I use a lambda on the association declaration that returns the right value according to the sub-class being used?